# sed inside a while loop

Tags: unix, ksh, aix

Below is the input file which is a template at this stage. I wish to replace various '-' in each line with actual data from a script.

```
030 230 - - - - - - -
230 330 - - NA NA - - -
330 430 - - NA NA - - -
430 530 - - - - - - -
530 630 - - NA NA - - -
630 2400 - - - - - - -
```

I wish to run the script and update **(in the same file)** one row at a time based upon the conditions in the script. The consecutive runs of the script would update other rows of the file. Below is the script.

```
##Time=`echo $(date) | awk -F ' ' '{print $4}' | awk -F ':' '{print $1$2}'`
Time=0330;

        while read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9
        do
                if (( "${Time}" >= "${f1}" && "${Time}" < "${f2}" ))
                then
                    sed "s/$f3/R/;s/$f4/F/;s/$f5/G/;s/$f6/H/;s/$f7/K/"
                    else
                    echo $f1 $f2 $f3 $f4 $f5 $f6 $f7 $f8 $f9                                
                fi
        done < consolidated.txt
```

Expected Output is below.

```
030 230 - - - - - - -
230 330 - - NA NA - - -
330 430 R F NA NA G H K
430 530 - - - - - - -
530 630 - - NA NA - - -
630 730 - - - - - - -
```

Then apply the script with Time=0600 on the above file to output something like this

```
030 230 - - - - - - -
230 330 - - NA NA - - -
330 430 R F NA NA G H K
430 530 - - - - - - -
530 630 A B NA NA D E F
630 730 - - - - - - -
```

But after running the script with Time=0330 (first run) it gives below output.

```
030 230 - - - - - - -
230 330 - - NA NA - - -
430 530 R F G H K - -
530 630 R F NA NA G H K
630 730 R F G H K - -
```

Also these changes are in the stdout and not being made in the file. 
I tried to use the sed flag -i which is not a recognized flag on my system.

I think there needs to be variation in the manner in which sed is being used but not sure what.

Comment: I've changed my answer considerably.  In general it is better to use the simplest available option, in this case a simple `echo`.  Also, if you need to keep the data inside the same file, it is better to have one script that does the processing and one that generates a temporary file and then overwrites the file.  e.g. `consolidated.txt | ./script.sh > /tmp/tmp_consolidated.txt && mv /tmp/tmp_consolidated.txt consolidated.txt`. This way, if something goes wrong anywhere in the script (not only inside the if), the original file is kept.

Answer (score 1):

A leading 0 indicates hexadecimal, to interpret a number as decimal use 10#n

```
if (( "10#${Time}" >= "10#${f1}" && "10#${Time}" < "10#${f2}" ))
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i` exists only in [GNU sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/).  AIX uses the common POSIX `sed`.  You must either output to another file and then overwrite the original one or install GNU sed.

I'd suggest installing GNU sed, never had issues in compiling it from source on AIX.

---

To be fair i have no idea why you are using `sed` in here

```
if (( "${Time}" >= "${f1}" && "${Time}" < "${f2}" ))
then
    sed "s/$f3/R/;s/$f4/F/;s/$f5/G/;s/$f6/H/;s/$f7/K/"
else
    echo $f1 $f2 $f3 $f4 $f5 $f6 $f7 $f8 f9
fi
```

You have read all space separated parts as variables therefore you can pretty much echo them out

```
if (( "${Time}" >= "${f1}" && "${Time}" < "${f2}" ))
then
    echo $f1 $f2 R F G H K $f8 $f9
else
    echo $f1 $f2 $f3 $f4 $f5 $f6 $f7 $f8 f9
fi
```

Also, i'd kill

```
< consolidated.txt
```

from the script.  Instead, i'd call the script with input and output each time, this gives some freedom in how you call it:

```
cat consolidated.txt | ./script.sh > consolidated_result.txt

./script <consolidated.txt >consolidated_result.txt

cat consolidated.txt | ./script.sh | ./further_processing.sh
```

(that would be the *nix way of doing things)

Comment: Well I figured that I can do the below as an alternative to -i option that I don't have. `sed "s/$f3/R/;s/$f4/F/;s/$f7/G/;s/$f8/H/;s/$f9/K/" consolidated.txt > consolidated.txt.tmp && mv consolidated.txt.tmp consolidated.txt`. But this is just the tip of my problem. You see the output of sed when executed in the while loop. That is the actual bugger. It is replacing the value in all the lines which is not desired.